# Does Visual Studio 2010 support Windows Metro style applications?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Does Visual Studio 2010 support Windows Metro style applications?

I am going to build a Microsoft WP7 application. I have Visual Studio 2010 and I have installed SDK7.1. I am not getting Metro style as an option so what do I have to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to get the Visual Studio 11 Dev Preview to start working on Metro apps.  The Express version can be downloaded in the Windows 8 Dev Preview.

Comment: ...thank you... can we convert Visual Studio 10 wp7 application to Visual Studio 11 metro style

Comment: No, you can't convert them.  They have to be re-written.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build a Windows Phone application, you can use Visual Studio 2010.  If you want to build a Windows 8 Metro application, you need the Windows 8 and Visual Studio 11 developer previews as @Kenneth-Funk mentioned.

You can't convert your WP7 app to Win 8 Metro.  You have to rewrite since you're moving from Silverlight to WinRT development.